# How to allow users to set their own aliases in Google Workspace?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want users in our organization to be able to set up and remove email aliases by themselves, so that they don't have to apply manually every time. I see that many schools have this feature in their self-service.

My initial idea was to give a group the permission to add and delete aliases. Users in the organization who need this function can obtain these permissions by joining the group themselves. However, after actual operation, I found that users can indeed obtain alias permissions, but they can only set aliases for others.
After searching, I learned that only super administrators can add aliases to their accounts. Is there any other simple way for users to set aliases by themselves? Thank you!